# Firefox downloading

Tags: file-organization

There are questions about this from years back, but the add-in recommended is no longer available.  I would like to do two things: 1. I want to organize the files that I download according to the file type, i.e. all jpeg files in a folder called photos, mp4 into a folder called videos, etc.  Also, I would like to make two copies.  One copy will go to the specific folder mentioned.  The other copy will go to my backup drive, a usb disk.

Comment: A similar way to achieve this outside of Firefox would be to just download normally, and have a script that runs periodically (like cron) that sorts by filetype for eg.

This can also mirror your files to a backup location if you wish. This won't work natively on Windows unfortunately but there may be an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the current API for Firefox addins doesn't allow automatic processing of downloads. You could try [Save In](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/save-in/) addin which is pretty close to what you want.